# Does my SignalR Hub class need any methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

According to the documentation I have read, in order to send a message to a client, I just need to call:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.foo(msg);
```

So... does the Hub class need any methods? If not, then all I have is an empty class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub 
{
}
```

which just seems like a pointless setup. Am I implementing this incorrectly? because it makes more sense to have methods in a hub class, and then call those methods to send a message to the client.

Also, in the hub itself, I can access Context.connectionId, so that I can get the requestor's connection Id and then stop the message from being fired to that client.... If a Hub shouldn't have methods, then is there a way to access the requestor's connection id?

Comment: Hub should have methods if your clients need to invoke some action at server. How do you plan to send the request from one client to the server to send a message to other clients?

Comment: Ah, that's kindda what I figured, if a client needed to talk to the server using SignalR, then the Hub will need methods. I'm actually calling the client side methods from my controller, rather than via SignalR.  So the user triggers an action in the controller, which then broadcasts the user's action to all clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need an empty HUB class declaration, because - It is actually just a proxy between the JS client and the controller so it could be empty since all methods are called via the Clients dynamic variable.

I mean without this , you can work, but you have to write JS for that. This is explained briefly in following link.

For more info refer this link - http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy

Comment: Even if you manually created a Hub proxy in JS instead of using the generated one, you would still need a corresponding Hub class on the server.